# How to use Ansible git module pull a branch with local changes?

Tags: git, ansible, devops

My git workspace is dirty, there are some local modifications. When I use command `git pull origin master` it works fine because there is no conflict.

But when I'm trying to use `Ansible` like
`git: repo=xxxx dest=xxx version={{branch}}`
I got error:

> Local modifications exist in repository (force=no)

If I add `force=yes`, then I will lose my local modifications.

What can I do to keep my local changes and pull latest commit from git by using Ansible git module.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot achieve it using the git module.

Ansible checks [the result of](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/source_control/git.py#L428):

```
git status --porcelain
```

and [aborts task execution](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/00911a75ad6635834b6d28eef41f197b2f73c381/source_control/git.py#L975) if there are local changes in tracked files, unless `force` parameter is set to `true`.

Comment: So, the only way is using shell command or try to keep a clean workspace?

Comment: Yes. Git module does not allow this and there is no other module which calls `git pull`.

Comment: Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like :

```
git: repo=xxxx dest=xxx version={{branch}} force=no
ignore_errors: yes
```

see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#ignoring-failed-commands

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by keeping the Ansible git module and **ignoring this specific error message** when it happens:

```yaml
- name: Clone repo
  git:
    repo: "{{ repo_url }}"
    dest: "{{ repo_dest }}"
  register: repo_clone
  failed_when:
    - repo_clone.failed
    - not 'Local modifications exist in repository' in repo_clone.msg
```

This task will fail either if the repo clone has failed, or another string than  '**Local modifications exist in repository**' is found in the fail message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stash/unstash functionality before/after cloning the repo along with the `force: yes`

```
- name: Stash git changes
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: "git stash"
    chdir: "/home/{{ common_user }}/nginx"

- name: Clone a Nginx repo
  ansible.builtin.git:
    repo: "{{ repo_url }}"
    dest: "/home/{{ common_user }}/nginx"
    force: yes

- name: Unstash git changes
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: "git stash pop"
    chdir: "/home/{{ common_user }}/nginx"
  register: unstash_output
  failed_when:
    - unstash_output.failed
    - not 'No stash entries found' in unstash_output.stderr
```

Tested with ansible version - 2.13.2